# How to disable the animation

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I got a donut chart made with Kendo in Angular and when I refresh the data, the chart make its animation. I'm trying to avoid this.

I tried to put animations = false and animation = false as attribute but it didn't work.
I looked for a solution, but I only found solutions with jQuery. I need a solution for Angular.

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-series>
      <kendo-chart-area
        [margin]="0"
        [height]="height"
        opacity="0"></kendo-chart-area>
      <kendo-chart-series-item
        type="donut"
        [data]="donutData"
        categoryField="kind"
        field="share"
        [holeSize]="25">
      </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
  </kendo-chart>
```

I want the chart doesn't make the animation when reload the data

Answer (score 1):

The key is called `transitions` as mentioned [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/ChartComponent/). So you need to add the attribute `[transitions]="false"` to your chart.

```
<kendo-chart [transitions]="false">
<!--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-area
      [margin]="0"
      [height]="height"
      opacity="0"></kendo-chart-area>
    <kendo-chart-series-item
      type="donut"
      [data]="donutData"
      categoryField="kind"
      field="share"
      [holeSize]="25">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
  <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
</kendo-chart>
```

Comment: @ManuelFernandez You're welcome! Can you mark the answer as accepted, since it solved your issue? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I had trouble finding this in the documentation.